# Python Convert Image to Sepia

Tags: python

This is a course project question.  I am working on this function 'mono' and not sure what I am doing wrong.  The formula for sepia is listed as:
*To simulate a sepia-toned photograph, you darken the green value to int(0.6 * brightness) and blue value to int(0.4 * brightness), producing a reddish-brown tone.*

I have used that formula in my code and the error I get in my course check module is that my answer is 76% incorrect.  Any advice for me on this?  Below is my code so far.

```
def mono(image, sepia=False):
    """
    Returns True after converting the image to monochrome.
    
    All plug-in functions must return True or False.  This function returns True 
    because it modifies the image. It converts the image to either greyscale or
    sepia tone, depending on the parameter sepia.
    
    If sepia is False, then this function uses greyscale.  For each pixel, it computes
    the overall brightness, defined as 
        
        0.3 * red + 0.6 * green + 0.1 * blue.
    
    It then sets all three color components of the pixel to that value. The alpha value 
    should remain untouched.
    
    If sepia is True, it makes the same computations as before but sets green to
    0.6 * brightness and blue to 0.4 * brightness.
    
    Parameter image: The image buffer
    Precondition: image is a 2d table of RGB objects
    
    Parameter sepia: Whether to use sepia tone instead of greyscale
    Precondition: sepia is a bool
    """
    # We recommend enforcing the precondition for sepia
    assert sepia == True or sepia == False
    
    height = len(image)
    width  = len(image[0])
        
    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            if sepia == False:
                pixel = image[row][col]
                pixel.red = int(0.3 * pixel.red + 0.6 * pixel.green + 0.1 * pixel.blue)
                pixel.green = pixel.red
                pixel.blue = pixel.red

    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            if sepia == True:
                pixel = image[row][col]
                sepi = int(pixel.red + pixel.green * 0.6 + pixel.blue * 0.4)
                                
    # Change this to return True when the function is implemented
    return True
```

Comment: You never assign the value of `sepi` to anything - you probably want to assign that back to the pixel (as you do in the grayscale version? Also, the `assert` at the start of your question doesn't really do anything, since it tests whether sepia is either True, or False - it'll be one of those. Instead of iterating over `image` twice and testing sepia inside the loop, iterate over it once and decide the value to set to r/g/b based on whether `sepia` is True or False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't use the `sepi` value. Also, you can combine the 2 loops.

```
def mono(image, sepia=False):
    height = len(image)
    width  = len(image[0])
        
    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            pixel = image[row][col]
            # Do the b&w calculation on the red pixel
            # Don't convert to int yet so we can use it later
            new_value = 0.3 * pixel.red + 0.6 * pixel.green + 0.1 * pixel.blue
            pixel.red = int(new_value)
            if sepia:
                # Do extra calculations on green & blue if sepia
                pixel.green = int(new_value * 0.6)
                pixel.blue = int(new_value * 0.4)
            else:
                pixel.green = pixel.red
                pixel.blue = pixel.red
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I definitely needed to combine the loops.  And now I see what I was doing wrong in the way of the calculation.  Greatly appreciate your help.